# Find condition for existence of a positive solution of a linear inequality $AX>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming

What is the necessary and sufficient condition  for the system of inequalities $AX > 0$  to have at least one positive solution, i.e, $X>0$ where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix ....?

Comment: by $>$ do you mean component wise **greater than**? have you heard of farkas' lemma?

Comment: yes...X>0 means if X=(x_{1},x_{2},........x_{n}) then x_{i}>0 for all i  between1 to n

Comment: Could you answer the second question (Knowledge of Farkas' lemma) ?

Comment: Actually Farkas Lemma tells AX=b has solution if $A^{t}y\geq 0$ and $b^{t}y<0 $ has no solution. But my question is whether $Ax> 0$ has any solution

Comment: In Farka's Lemma also it is a inequality....there is no definite thing on the right hand side.....So we can't ensure the no solution thing from rank B=rank[B|b1] as b1 is not definite here......B is  obtained from A^t Y>=0 and b^t y<0....so what is condition of solution existence or non existence of system of inequalities.....

Comment: Square matrices for which there exists $x>0$ such that $Ax>0$ are called semi-positive. An example of a family of semi-positive matrices is the M-matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix. You may want to do some searching from there, but I don't know of any good necessary conditions.

Comment: i'm studying this problem also. DId you find anything new about it? Thanks a lot.